# How to add check boxes to a user form dynamically through a loop in VBA?

Tags: excel, dynamic, userform, vba

### Add Check Box to UserForms Dynamically through code

I am trying to collect all file names in a specific folder in multiple check boxes in a user form so that i can select one by one to move to another folder....after adding one check box i couldn't add another during run time please help.

---

```
Private Sub Download_file_Click()
Dim wrkbk As Workbook
Dim ofs As New FileSystemObject
Dim ofolder As Folder
Dim ofile As File
Dim mars_path As String
Dim chkBox As MSForms.CheckBox
Dim files_count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim sheet_name As String
Dim NewCheckBox As MSForms.CheckBox
Dim file_name As String

Set wrkbk = Application.Workbooks("Download files.xlsm")


mars_path = input_path.Value
    If mars_path = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please provide input path first!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
If ofs.FolderExists(mars_path) Then
        Set ofolder = ofs.GetFolder(mars_path)
        MsgBox "files are present!!"
End If

files_count = ofolder.Files.Count

sub_folder_count = ofolder.SubFolders.Count
MsgBox "# files =" & files_count & "and # folder =" & sub_folder_count


'********folder check***************
    i = 1
    
            'Create the User Form
            Set myform = wrkbk.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)
            With myform
            .Properties("caption") = "New Form"
            End With

    For Each ofile In ofolder.Files
        file_name = ofile.Name
        MsgBox file_name
        
        'Create CheckBox

        Set NewCheckBox = myform.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox."&i)
               
        With NewCheckBox
            .Caption = file_name
        End With
    i = i + 1
   Next ofile
i = 1
    For Each SubFolders In ofolder.SubFolders
        file_name = SubFolders.Name
        MsgBox file_name
        
        'Create CheckBox
        Set NewCheckBox = myform.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox." & i)
        With NewCheckBox
            .Caption = file_name
        End With
    i = i + 1
    Next SubFolders

Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you use a listbox? It's much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 Set NewCheckBox = myform.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "Check" & i, true) ' first string must be this, 2nd is name, 3rd is visible=true.
```

you still might want to add the new controls to an array, collection, or dictionary (my prefered, because easier to remove stuff and test if exists).

Hope this helps.
Patrick Lepelletier.

edit: "more" help by pressing F1 in VBE on the line Userform1.controls.add , or this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251373.aspx