# How do you programmatically create a new checkbox on an existing userform using a command button in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I tried `

`Set chkBox = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.i", "Checkbox" & i)
         '.Object.Caption = Range("D3").Value`

I even tried

```
With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1", _
    Left:=51.75, Top:=183, Width:=120, Height:=19.5)
    .Name = "NewCheckBox"
    .Object.Caption = Range("D3").Value
```

But this gives me a checkbox but not on my created userform  but the activesheet I'm on.

Any suggestions

Comment: For the second piece of code, it looks like it's because you are qualifying the `Add` method with `ActiveSheet`. What if you change `ActiveSheet` to `UserForm1`? Additionally for the first part it should be "Forms.Checkbox.1". Where is `i` being set?

Comment: In your first bit it should be `Forms.Checkbox.1`. Where is this code?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41169068/1726522).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the most primitive form I wrote, this added a checkbox (to the upper left corner of the UserForm1)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

        Dim chkBox As Control

        Set chkBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "checkbox")

End Sub
```

You'll want to play with the positioning and such.

Comment: This worked thank you very much, though I will have to name it programmatically which should be no problem